Multithreading slows down loop
I realize there are a lot of questions asking why multithreading can slowdown a program but it always seems to come down to threads aggressively locking shared state.  In my case I'm not using any locks.
I have a TCP client that is receiving a byte array that contains a multi channel time series.  The samples are interweaved by channel (1st C1 sample, 1st C2 sample, 2nd C1 sample, 2nd C2 sample) and encoded as little endian shorts and I want to save each channel in a std::vector.  I'm receiving a lot of data from several hundred channels and I thought I'd be able to divide up the data and multithread the work however using multiple threads actually seems to slow the code down.
I've written the following reproduction.  The average time spent in each thread increases as I reduce band_size;
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

char data[1048576];

int main()
{
  for (auto& d : data) {
    d = std::rand();
  }
  auto nchans = 769;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> out(nchans, std::vector<double>());
  auto band_size = nchans/12;

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  std::atomic_uint total_ns = 0;
  for (auto c = 0; c < nchans; c += band_size) {
    threads.emplace_back([&, c] {
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      for (auto subc = 0; subc < band_size && c + subc < nchans; ++subc) {
        auto channel = c + subc;
        for (auto i = 2 * (c + subc); i + 1 < sizeof(data); i += 2 * nchans) {
          short sample = data[i] + (data[i + 1] << 8);
          out[channel].push_back(sample);
        }
      }
      total_ns += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    });
  }
  for (auto& promise : threads) {
    promise.join();
  }
  std::cout << "done " << (total_ns / threads.size()) / 1e6 << "ms";
}


The shared state here could be the heap: each thread causes heap allocations with push_back call, and there's locking going on in the heap manager. See whether the outcome changes if you call reserve on all vectors in out beforehand.

How many cores do you have available? If the threads are active, and these look like they run non-stop until they're done, too many threads and the poor CPU will wind up spending more time dealing with threads fighting over resources than it will doing productive work.

Possibly false sharing since each thread is indirectly messing with out.  push_back will change non-heap state even if it doesn't have to reallocate (size).  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE for an excellent example and a deeper explanation.

With a few tweaks to the code, I was able to get the 'expected' results on my computer. I would be interested to see how this test plays out on other hardware.
I was using gcc 12.2.1 with the compile command line g++ --std=c++23 -O3 main.cpp -lpthread -o main
First, I added an external loop to quickly get multiple results for different numbers of threads. Additionally I measured total time as well as per thread time to get a better idea what is going on globally.
There is one logic bug in the code on the line
auto band_size = nchans/12;
It should be: auto band_size = nchans/12 + 1;
With the first version, it was ending up with an extra thread that did not have any work to do which was messing up the per thread time calculation.
For example, if it divided nchans by 2, it would get 3 threads with c=0, 384, and 768 respectively. The last thread had hardly any work to do but the total time was still getting divided by 3.
Another thing that I changed was I reserved space in the output vectors. If the space was not reserved, the timing results were all over the place.
Finally, I multiplied the input data size by 10 to help reduce measurement noise.
For fun, I added an additional option that give the CPUs some busy work to do. The test was run with and without the additional work enabled.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

static const int DATA_SIZE = 10485760;
char data[DATA_SIZE];

void run(int threadCount, bool doWork)
{

  for (int i = 0; i<DATA_SIZE; i++) {
    data[i] = std::rand();
  }
  auto nchans = 769;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> out(nchans, std::vector<double>());
  for(auto & vec: out) {
    vec.reserve(DATA_SIZE/nchans+1);
  }


  auto band_size = nchans/threadCount +1;

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  uint total_ns = 0;
  std::atomic_uint per_thread_ns = 0;
 

  auto total_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for (auto c = 0; c < nchans; c += band_size) {
    threads.emplace_back([&, c] {      
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      for (auto subc = 0; subc < band_size && c + subc < nchans; ++subc) {
        auto channel = c + subc;
        for (auto i = 2 * (c + subc); i + 1 < DATA_SIZE; i += 2 * nchans) {
          short sample = data[i] + (data[i + 1] << 8);

          double value;
          if(doWork) {
            value = std::sin(sample) + std::cos(sample) + std::exp(sample);
          } else {
            value = sample;
          }

          out[channel].push_back(value);
        }
      }
      per_thread_ns += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
    });
  }
  for (auto& promise : threads) {
    promise.join();
  }
  total_ns += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - total_start).count();
  
  printf("threads=%2d total=%5.2fms perThread=%5.2f\n", threadCount, total_ns/1e6, (per_thread_ns / threads.size()) / 1e6  );
}

int main() {

  std::cout << "Warm up the memory\n";
  run(1, false);

  std::cout << "\n\nWith no work\n";
  for(int i = 1; i<24; i++) {
    run(i, false);
  }
  std::cout << "\n\nwith work\n";
  for(int i = 1; i<24; i++) {
    run(i, true);
  }

  return 0;
}

And below are the results for my computer. Please note that my computer has 8 cores, which will help explain the results.
With both the 'no work' and 'work' options, the per thread time decreased with every additional thread. However the total time decreased for the first 6 or 7 threads then flattened out as there are no more cores to use.
Warm up the memory
threads= 1 total=24.48ms perThread=24.20


With no work
threads= 1 total=13.15ms perThread=12.84
threads= 2 total= 7.28ms perThread= 6.93
threads= 3 total= 4.76ms perThread= 4.47
threads= 4 total= 4.39ms perThread= 4.11
threads= 5 total= 3.80ms perThread= 3.39
threads= 6 total= 3.29ms perThread= 2.93
threads= 7 total= 3.29ms perThread= 2.82
threads= 8 total= 5.28ms perThread= 3.21
threads= 9 total= 4.49ms perThread= 2.52
threads=10 total= 4.11ms perThread= 2.12
threads=11 total= 3.87ms perThread= 1.90
threads=12 total= 3.52ms perThread= 1.64
threads=13 total= 3.64ms perThread= 1.73
threads=14 total= 3.50ms perThread= 1.53
threads=15 total= 3.53ms perThread= 1.42
threads=16 total= 3.87ms perThread= 1.31
threads=17 total= 3.84ms perThread= 1.30
threads=18 total= 3.79ms perThread= 1.19
threads=19 total= 3.72ms perThread= 1.17
threads=20 total= 4.13ms perThread= 1.08
threads=21 total= 4.63ms perThread= 1.27
threads=22 total= 4.75ms perThread= 1.04
threads=23 total= 3.77ms perThread= 0.95


With work
threads= 1 total=194.74ms perThread=194.46
threads= 2 total=104.82ms perThread=103.87
threads= 3 total=70.05ms perThread=66.72
threads= 4 total=51.93ms perThread=50.05
threads= 5 total=63.21ms perThread=49.88
threads= 6 total=38.83ms perThread=36.46
threads= 7 total=32.19ms perThread=30.68
threads= 8 total=38.35ms perThread=30.56
threads= 9 total=35.48ms perThread=26.54
threads=10 total=33.29ms perThread=23.69
threads=11 total=41.73ms perThread=23.62
threads=12 total=40.59ms perThread=20.68
threads=13 total=36.41ms perThread=21.18
threads=14 total=39.62ms perThread=20.18
threads=15 total=34.93ms perThread=18.06
threads=16 total=32.73ms perThread=15.59
threads=17 total=33.86ms perThread=14.73
threads=18 total=34.69ms perThread=13.27
threads=19 total=33.03ms perThread=11.59
threads=20 total=32.17ms perThread=10.54
threads=21 total=30.57ms perThread=10.35
threads=22 total=30.28ms perThread= 9.61
threads=23 total=33.96ms perThread=10.38


I decided to play with this and I'm almost positive you have false sharing (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE for a great example around the 4 minute mark and an fantastic explanation for the rest of the talk).  By using local vectors in the loop, I'm getting about double the performance.
(p is my modified version, p2 is your original code).
$ ./p
done 7.53478ms
$ ./p
done 8.08364ms
$ ./p2
done 14.434ms
$ ./p2
done 13.2935ms

I'm compiling both programs using gcc-13.3.1 on an x86_64 linux system using the following flags: -O2 -Wall -Wextra p2.cpp -o p2 -std=c++20 -fsanitize=thread (thread sanitizer was turned on to try and make sure I wasn't introducing a race, and I didn't bother to turn it back off).
The entirety of my change is here:
diff -u p2.cpp p.cpp 
--- p2.cpp      2024-08-19 21:08:54.568141987 -0600
+++ p.cpp       2024-08-19 21:08:31.635458341 -0600
@@ -21,10 +21,12 @@
       auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
       for (auto subc = 0; subc < band_size && c + subc < nchans; ++subc) {
         auto channel = c + subc;
+        std::vector<double> lo;
         for (auto i = 2 * (c + subc); i + 1 < sizeof(data); i += 2 * nchans) {
           short sample = data[i] + (data[i + 1] << 8);
-          out[channel].push_back(sample);
+          lo.push_back(sample);
         }
+        out[channel] = std::move(lo);
       }
       total_ns += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
     });

Short explanation of what I believe is happening: when you call push_back, you're manipulating non-heap data (specifically the vector's size, and sometimes capacity and whatever pointer to the underlying buffer is used).  This is causing false sharing since any time a thread touches size, it's forcing a cache flush for a lot of your other vectors.  This is covered in far more detail in the Scott Meyers talk I linked above.

The first time I observed more threads slowing down my code was in a debug build of my cmake/ninja project.  Then I put my current example in visual studio and saw the same thing.  Sometime later I tried running a release build of my cmake/ninja project and my visual studio solution in release mode and now I see threading absolutely speeding up my code.
Are there any compiler flags you think could cause this?  I've been building directly with cl and trying various flags and can't reproduce the inverse thread to speed relationship.
